# Regex PHP - Get specific text including new lines and multiple spaces

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match, text-manipulation

I was trying to get the text starting from *css:{(some text...)}* up to the ending bracket only, not including the texts below in another text file using php.

**test.sample**

```
just a sample text

css:{

 "css/test.css",
    "css/test2.css"

}

sample:text{

}
```

I'm using **vscode/sublime** *search and replace* tool to test my regex syntax and nothing is wrong, I successfully get the text that I want including all the new lines and spaces inside, but when i tried to apply it on php, the regex that I created doesn't work, it cannot find the text that im looking for.

here is my code:

**myphp.php**

```
$file = file_get_contents("src/page/test.sample");
echo $file . "<br>";
if (preg_match_all("/(css\s*\n*:\s*\n*\{\s*\n*)+((.|\n\S)*|(.|\n\s)*)(\n*)(\}\W)$/", $file)) {
    echo "Success";
} else {
    echo "Failed!";
}
```

This is my regex that I just created.

> (css\s*\n*:\s*\n*{\s*\n*)+((.|\n\S)*|(.|\n\s)*)(\n*)(}\W)$

Please help me, Im open for any suggestion, Im a newbie on regular expression, Im lacking on knowledge about the logic of it.

thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to extract just the "css" styles, or everything in the file after the opening "css:{"?  If the latter, you could use `substr()` and `strpos()` which would be much more straightforward.  To answer your question specifically, you probably need the "m" modifier since you're dealing with multiple lines: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: Yes I'm trying to extract only the block of code css, I provided an example text because the file that Im going to extract also contains another data that needs to get extracted too. Basically I'm trying to make my own framework that you can include your css, body and Javascript in that format. I will check that link right now and also that 'm' modifier I don't really know that. Thanks

Comment: Also, that regex is really complicated.  Personally, I'd just try to extract the text between { and }, then use `explode()` to get the component parts.  You might want to reconsider using this type of format.  There are lots of configuration formats out there (JSON, .ini, YAML) that have solved this problem.

Comment: yeah you are right! this regex is just so complicated, I only use it because i don't really know much about php file handling, I just found out today based on the answer of @Alex, you can actually open the file stream and read it line by line, thank you I tried using your suggestion the ```strpos()```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys I found the solution! base on the answer of @alex

> Dont really know if I am implementing this right.

Here is my code

```
$src = "src/page/darwin.al"; //get the source file
      $file = fopen($src,"rb"); //I dont really know what 'rb' means, I guess it simply means, 'not a commong text file'?, search for it!
      $found = false;
      $css = false;
      while($line = fgets($file)){ //read every line of text and assign that line of text in a variable $line

            if(strpos(preg_replace("/\s*/", "", $line), "css:{") === 0){ //if the current line is == 'css:{' <the thing that Im looking for,
                $found = true;
                $css = true;
            }elseif($css && strpos(preg_replace("/\s*/", "", $line),"}") === 0){ //If we are still inside the css block and found the '{'
                echo $line;
                break;
            }

            if ($found) {
                echo preg_replace("/\s*/", "", $line); //remove every whitespace!
            }

      }
      fclose($file);//close the file
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this my friend:**

```
<?php

$file = "testfile.php"; // call the file

$f = fopen($file, 'rb'); // open the file

$found = false;

while ($line = fgets($f, 1000)) { // read every line of the file

    if ($found) {

       echo $line;

       continue;

    }

    if (strpos($line, "css:") !== FALSE) { // if we found the word 'css:' we print everything after that

      $found = true;

    }

}
```

Comment: This will print the file from `css:` until the end of file, they want to print until the closing curly brace.

Comment: Oh yeah that's an idea, then I just need to add if strpos is equal to '}' then I'll exit the loop right?

Comment: @DarwinMarcelo sorry about that, i see you already find the answer by yourself, glad to know that. Have a nice day.